# Update entry programatically

Tags: plugin-development

Im trying to update an entry field programatically. I can load an entry by any field with a function i created

```
    /**
 * Returns an element by any attribute.
 *
 * @param int $elementId
 * @param string|null $type
 * @param string|null $localeId
 * @param string $localeId
 * @return BaseElementModel|null
 */
public function getElementByField($elementId, $elementType = null, $localeId = null, $field)
{
    if (!$elementId)
    {
        return null;
    }

    if (!$elementType)
    {
        $elementType = craft()->elements->getElementTypeById($elementId);

        if (!$elementType)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria($elementType);
    $criteria->$field = $elementId;
    $criteria->locale = $localeId;
    $criteria->status = null;
    $criteria->localeEnabled = null;
    return $criteria->first();
}
```

but i cant save the new values of the fields i want.
This is my save code:

```
$entry = $this->getElementByField("3081001100390", ElementType::Entry, null, "variantSku");
    $entry->variantSku = 1;
    craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);
```

And the error is  Property "Craft\EntryModel.variantSku" is not defined. I know the variantSku exists since im loading a product by that attribute and i can see it when dumping $entry->variantSku.

Complete error here: https://www.diigo.com/item/image/4u33k/972k

Did anyone achieved this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research, i found a way to achieve this. Here is my full controller:

```
<?php
  namespace Craft;

  class Module_ControlController extends BaseController {
   protected $allowAnonymous = true;
public function actionChangeStock()
{
    $entry = $this->getElementByField("3081001100390", ElementType::Entry, null, "variantSku");
    $entry->enabled = false;
    $entry->getContent()->setAttributes(array(
        'variantSku' => "Hello my friend!",
        'variantStock'  => "3"
    ));
    $success = craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);
    die(var_dump($success));
}

/**
 * Returns an element by any attribute.
 *
 * @param int $elementId
 * @param string|null $type
 * @param string|null $localeId
 * @return BaseElementModel|null
 */
public function getElementByField($elementId, $elementType = null, $localeId = null, $field)
{
    if (!$elementId)
    {
        return null;
    }

    if (!$elementType)
    {
        $elementType = craft()->elements->getElementTypeById($elementId);

        if (!$elementType)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria($elementType);
    $criteria->$field = $elementId;
    $criteria->locale = $localeId;
    $criteria->status = null;
    $criteria->localeEnabled = null;
    return $criteria->first();
}}
```

Comment: This will not work on Craft 3. Any idea on how to implement this login in craft 3? The documentation is not helping me out...